# Seed entity using sql script .net core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I’m having problem right now, I have 2 databases where db A works as repository (we bring data from there and not mapped with EF) and db B (this mapped with EF)
Now we need to create a new entity on db B based on the data from one table that is on the db A, I have a query to bring the data from A but I don’t know how to fill the entity in table B with that data. And both tables are in different environments